# Interpolate f at the points $x-h , x $ and $x+h$ by a quadratic polynomial $p(x)$

Tags: interpolation

Interpolate f at the points $x-h , x$  and  $x+h$ by a quadratic polynomial $p(x)$.

> Let $ \ p(x)=a+bx+cx^{2} \ $.    Now,\begin{align} p(x-h)=f(x-h)=a+b(x-h)+c(x-h)^{2},  \\p(x)=f(x)=a+bx+cx^{2} , \\ p(x+h)=f(x+h)=a+b(x+h)+c(x+h)^{2},   \end{align}

But now this is tedius to find out the constants   $a, b, c$.

Any help please.

Comment: What do you mean by tedious? You can plug this into a software like mathematica or do the calculations by hand.

Comment: I don't have software facility but I want to mean is this the process for quadratic polynomial approximation ?

Comment: In hand it is being lengthy , please help me with short calculation

Comment: The calculations are not really short, but the problem is setup correctly, you have three equations and three unknowns since you assume $x,h$ is known.